# Add -0.5 to a value below 0 and add 0.5 to value above 0 in r

Tags: r

I maybe have a strange question...I have a dataframe as below:

```
     Station         Mean_length   Diff
     1 AMEL           28.1        -2.91 
     2 AMRU           21.1        -9.90 
     3 BALG           31.0         0    
     4 BORK           30.1        -0.921
     5 BUSU           22.6        -8.38 
     6 CADZ           28.5         2.46 
     7 DOLL           27.9        -3.07 
     8 EGMO           28.3        -2.69 
     9 EIER           30.8         0.233
    10 FANO           23.1        -7.89
```

Now from column "Diff" I want to get a new column and I want to add -0.5 to a value below 0 and add 0.5 to value above 0.
So I get a new dataframe like this:

```
     Station         Mean_length   Diff   Diff05
     1 AMEL           28.1        -2.91    -3.41     (-0.5)
     2 AMRU           21.1        -9.90    -13.8     (-0.5)
     3 BALG           31.0         0       0.5       (+0.5)
     4 BORK           30.1        -0.921   -1.421    (-0.5)
     5 BUSU           22.6        -8.38    -8.88     (-0.5)
     6 CADZ           28.5         2.46    2.96      (+0.5)
     7 DOLL           27.9        -3.07    -3.57     (-0.5)
     8 EGMO           28.3        -2.69    -3.19     (-0.5)
     9 EIER           30.8         0.233   0.733     (+0.5)
    10 FANO           23.1        -7.89    -8.39     (-0.5)
```

How can I tackle this? Is there something in dplyr possible? with the 'ifelse' function? recognizing values when they are haven the '-' in front of them....

Thank you I advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(Diff05 = if_else(Diff < 0, Diff - 0.5, Diff + 0.5))
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   station Mean_length   Diff  Diff05
   <chr>         <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 AMEL           28.1 -2.91   -3.41 
 2 AMRU           21.1 -9.9   -10.4  
 3 BALG           31    0       0.5  
 4 BORK           30.1 -0.921  -1.42 
 5 BUSU           22.6 -8.38   -8.88 
 6 CADZ           28.5  2.46    2.96 
 7 DOLL           27.9 -3.07   -3.57 
 8 EGMO           28.3 -2.69   -3.19 
 9 EIER           30.8  0.233   0.733
10 FANO           23.1 -7.89   -8.39
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way:

```
df$Diff05 <- df$Diff + 0.5 * sign(df$Diff)

  Station Mean_length   Diff  Diff05
1     AMEL        28.1 -2.910  -3.410
2     AMRU        21.1 -9.900 -10.400
3     BALG        31.0  0.000   0.000
4     BORK        30.1 -0.921  -1.421
5     BUSU        22.6 -8.380  -8.880
6     CADZ        28.5  2.460   2.960
7     DOLL        27.9 -3.070  -3.570
8     EGMO        28.3 -2.690  -3.190
9     EIER        30.8  0.233   0.733
10    FANO        23.1 -7.890  -8.390
```

You could also use `df$Diff + (df$Diff>0) - 0.5`

Answer (score 1):

The logical way

```
df$Diff05 <- ifelse(test = df$Diff < 0, yes = df$Diff - 0.5, no = df$Diff + 0.5)
```